# How to transpose column in several rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a way to transpose one column in excel into several rows. For example I have one column with 100 rows and I want to transpose it but also split it in several rows with 3 columns.

I have this:

```
21
34
2
56
23
12
34
18
22
...
```

I need this:

```
21 34  2
56 23 12
34 18 22
...
```

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

[image]

The formula used in `C1` translates to:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$9,ROW(A1)*3-3+COLUMN(A1))
```

You can drag it sideways and down.